# 2 floating columns pushing footer

Tags: css-float, multiple-columns

I have a little problem with my web page.
I have 2 columns with left and right floating.
Right column have multiple h1 and p tags with content in it.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">...</div>
        <div id="right">
          <h1>...</h1>
          <p>...</p> 
        </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Without content in left column, right column is pushing the footer down and changing wrappers height as it should. But i have a problem with left column. When there is more content in it (height is bigger than right column) insted of pushing footer down, left column content displays on top of footer and changing the height of entire body rather than changing height of wrapper.

```
 #wrapper {
    width: 980px;}
    #left {
            float: left;  
            width: 750px;
            position: absolute;}
    #right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;}
```

Without absolute position of left div right div is pushed down under the left one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help...

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1050px; <----
}
#left {
    float: left;  
    width: 750px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Your wrapper body width needs to be equal or greater to the left and right combined.

Also you may notice that your `h1` and `p` tags cause a little bit of a top margin - not sure if you meant it this way but you can fix this by doing

```
h1,p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

or just apply it to the whole body.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: i feel kinda stupid now. I created a completly new design and it works now, no need of absolute position for left div.

Answer (score 0):

Patosai's answer is correct, and i'm not sure on what your use case is for this code.

But to make sure the `<div id="left">` and `<div id="right">` never collapse under one another, you could try using percentages:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    float: left;  
    width: 75%;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}
```

See a working example here: http://codepen.io/yoomee/pen/KuzHB